# Teeth friendly alcohol drinks

Tags: ph

What is the best alcohol for your teeth according to the pH?

Is it true that if the acidity of the drink is higher (and ph is lower) than it's worse for your teeth (enamel erosion + bacteria friendly acidic environment) than if the alcohol drink is less acidic?

Does vodka have the highest pH of all the alcohol drinks out there and therefore is the best for your teeth?

Comment: Why the downvote? Should I move it to biology SE ? But I personally think that biochemistry is much closer to chemistry than biology.

Comment: Maybe the title could be better.. more related to chemistry than medical health... (But this is a my opinion...)

Comment: Ethanolic KOH, clearly. Great for your teeth, terrible for your rest of you.

Comment: Worth mentioning that alcohol has a tendency to reduce salive excretion which in turn increases growth of bacteria.

Answer (score 1):

Is quite reductive think that pH is the onlyfactor that determinate the health of your teeth, the content of carbohydrate have a strong effect too.
However in fact to my knowledge clear vodaka have one of the highest pH and very few carbohydrates so indeed is one of the most "teeth friendly alcohol drink".
These is take from *Victor R. Preedy, Ronald Ross Watson Academic Press, 24/dic/2004 Comprehensive Handbook of Alcohol Related Pathology* with the adding of Vodka and Coca Cola.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
Alcolic \space beverage & Carboydrate \space content(\%) & pH \\ \hline
Beer               & 3.0-5.0   &  4.1-4.5    \\ \hline
Wine & 0.0-12.9 &  2.8-3.8     \\ \hline
Sweet \space liquor           & 30.0-31.0 & 3.3-3.9 \\ \hline
Strong \space alcohol & 0.0-1.2 &   6.5-6.9\\ \hline
Vodka                & very \space few       & 6.0-7.0        \\ \hline
Coca Cola & 10.6(?) & 2.8\\ \hline
\end{array}

However keep out  from Vodka lemon!

Answer (score 1):

Sugar content will be the determining factor in tooth decay, my dentist informed me when I asked her this very question that it's not the inherent acidity of the drink / food stuff that does the damage.

What does cause damage is the bacteria in your mouth digesting simple sugars over a long period of time. From [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_caries);

> Tooth decay disease is caused by specific types of bacteria that
>   produce acid in the presence of fermentable carbohydrates such as
>   sucrose, fructose, and glucose.

I took this advice as meaning I should take all my drinks neat of course.

Comment: I think he told you just the A and forget to tell you the B. And that is that the enamel is destroyed by acid stuff in general (as all human cells) but most of them can be repaired or replaced by other cells. Everytime you take a drink of a soda you get 20 seconds of acid attack on your teeth. Which in time will eat away at your enamel and then cause a cavity. The increased acid strips the natural protective layer on your teeth and the enamel begins to slowly lose its natural minerals and therefore breakdown, causing decay.

Comment: @Derfder You are right that pH matters, but mostly wrong that it matters much. If you drink lots of coke or some fruit juices, the acid will erode enamel, but you have to drink a lot to do more damage than the sugar content will cause. Most alcoholic drinks will not be either so sweet or so acid as coke (unless they contain coke, of course) so will cause far less damage. Sweet alcoholic drinks will most damage you because of the sugar not the alcohol.